# How to interface AMBE-4020 vocoder chip to Ti CC2640R2F Microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller

How to interface AMBE-4020 vocoder chip to Ti CC2640R2F Microcontroller?
The user manual of  AMBE-4020 has not given any detail about this.

Comment: Through the UART interface, section 2.6 of the manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general procedure for connecting another chip to a microcontroller is:

Read the microcontroller datasheet.

Read the other chip datasheet.

Assuming a appropriate microcontroller was picked in the first place, think about what I/O you want to use on the micro.

Wire it all up.

Write the code.

I don't see any reason for this process to be different in your case.